# How can I set a "root node" for rabl template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

I am building a Rails 3.2 app and I am using Rabl templates.
I would like to add a "root node" that displays the total number of records.
The solution below adds the total node to each record. I want it on top of all records.

```
collection @projects

extends "projects/_base"

node(:total_entries) { @projects.total_count }
```

*I want it to be like this:*

```
- total_entries: 3
-- Entry 1
-- Entry 2
-- Entry 3
```

Answer (score 0):

From [an example in the READM](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#object-assignment)E:

```
object false
node(:total_entries) { @foos.count }
child(@foos, :object_root => false) { attributes :name }
```

=>

```
{
  "total_entries": 2,
  "foos": [
    {
      "name": "Jane"
    },
    {
      "name": "John"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or don't set the `object_root` in to generate:

```
{
  "total_entries": 2,
  "foos": [
    {
      "foo": {
        "name": "Jane"
      }
    },
    {
      "foo": {
        "name": "John"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```